# Strange Result for Math.pow() in JavaScript across different Browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, math, pow

Maybe this only happens in chrome latest version.

Some weird behavior for the **negative exponent** value only in the **Chrome browser**.

I already checked with different browsers & find it really weird. As **FireFox** & **Chromium** will show the exact same result while **Chrome latest version** will show the different result for some of the examples. And I don't know what's going on?

Here are my findings for different browsers...

### FireFox

[image]

### Chromium

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

## Weird Thing!!

For the `Math.pow(10,-4)` and `Math.pow(10,-5)`, the answer should be `0.0001` and `0.00001` respectively but why chrome's latest version shows`0.00009999999999999999` and `0.000009999999999999999` respectively!!

Can anyone have an explanation for the above scenario that why chrome is doing like this?

***FYI** - All browser's version already mentioned in images.*

Comment: What's different here isn't `Math.pow` (it's standardized and does give the same result) but `Number.toString`. EcmaScript doesn't specify a precise algorithm for this conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: [Floating-Point Questions Are Endless on stackoverflow.com](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/)

Answer (score 3):

> Returns an **implementation-dependent** approximation of the result of raising *base* to the power *exponent*.

https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-applying-the-exp-operator

0.0001 is the next representable number above 0.00009999999999999999. (The results differ by one *unit of least precision*.)

This appears to have changed in 74.0.3700.0 ([changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/fd651a3daf449e8746a901262537831764cf0d5d..237428d3c3e3f640b821272e17f1cc582380b668)), corresponding to a [V8 roll](https://crrev.com/630388) to 7.4.113, including this commit:

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/98453126c109016c9d32c6ebd89dd83f69dd8efb
>
> [builtins] [turbofan] Refactor Float64Pow to use single implementation
>
> Remove platform-specific Float64Pow implementations and utils Pow in
> favor of a base::ieee754::pow implementation.
>
> This unifies the implementation of pow for the compiler, wasm, and
> runtime.

So they switched the implementation of Pow to something else.

To demonstrate that we're getting a *different number* and it's not related to the float-to-decimal conversion:

```
> 10**-4 == 1e-4
```

Or, if you're not convinced and want to explore floats at a low level, dump the number as hex:

(Requires Firefox 67.)

```js
from_bits = b => new Float64Array(new BigUint64Array([b]).buffer)[0]
to_bits = f => new BigUint64Array(new Float64Array([f]).buffer)[0]

console.log(to_bits(Math.pow(10,-4)).toString(16))
```

I get 3f1a36e2eb1c432d in Firefox and 3f1a36e2eb1c432c in Chrome.

Comment: @JohnColeman It's close enough. It's enough decimal places to uniquely determine a specific 64-bit float as opposed to some other number. Try the commentary at https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/flt2dec/mod.rs.html

Comment: The fraction on the smallest positive 64-bit float has 751 digits when written in base 10, but we usually write 5e-324 out of convenience, since these numbers are usually used as approximations to what we actually meant.